# Взять значение prefab'а

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть prefab A с скриптом, в скрипте пара public полей.

В другом скрипте prefab'a B нахожу colider'ы, среди них с нужным тэгом, как с помощью этих колайдеров достучаться к значениям в скрипте для prefab'a А? И возможно ли это.

**P.S.** прошу прощения за кривой вопрос, в спецификации unity еще не сильно силен, буду рад конструктивной критике)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно найти объект на котором повешен скрипт и вызвать 
MyScript script = GetComponent<MyScript>();